Why is the ceiling paint peeling off?
I believe I have a leak in a bathroom I do not use.
Above is the Attic, where there must be a couple of PVC water lines, and the drain line from the AC/Furnace. This part of the attic is pretty inaccessible so I am looking for ideas to get a better understanding as to what is going on.
Should I make a tiny hole in the ceiling to insert an exploration camera? Make 12"x12" hole in the ceiling in between the recessed light and the damaged area?
Right now, the ceiling feels dry to the touch, but I have observed the overall condition of the paint degrade overtime.




Might just be a bad tape job when they did the drywall.  Water leaks tend to stain also, but that looks like the tape is just peeling.

so if this is the case, should I peel off the paint, then paint the ceiling and keep an eye on it?

Will need to re-tape that joint with tape and drywall mud.

That's not really the paint that's peeling. The paint is stuck to the drywall tape as it should be, but the tape is peeling off the joint in the ceiling drywall.

Could be an effect of humidity from running the shower. I see the tape is right above your shower head. Paint on our bathroom used to "alligator" due to humidity. Inspect for mold prior to repair.

no we do not run this shower/bathtub.
